# Exporting Facebook Discussions topics

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, export

On Oct. 31, Facebook is going to remove the "Discussions" app and I would like to know if there is some way to export the topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The info on the discussions tab is unfortunately not available via the API.  You would have to  export it manually (copy and paste).

Comment: I figured as much, but I thought it was worth asking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a new application called Forum for Pages that replaces the discussion tabs and that allows you to automatically re-import all your threads from the old discussion tab: http://www.facebook.com/202980683107053. All your discussions will be backed up in just a few minutes.